# parpic problem (indentation)

Tags: environments

I like to use parpic to insert in the beginning of a paragraph some photo of scientist --- mainly eps files. Unfortunately some times, it indents the whole paragraph. Is this a know bug or the result of a clash between packages? I do not believe to the second proposition since in the same text it is not systematic.

I add an example

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that demonstrates the problem? As it seems to be an intermittent problem it might be difficult to isolate but without an example to work with this will be almost impossible to understand and fix.

Comment: Andrew thanks for your kind response. I have add a picture to show what happen. I have tried to make a minimal example but in that case there is no problem.

Comment: I suggest using the `\InsertBoxL`  command from the plainTeX macro package `insbox`.